# Tag Editor badge

Tags: support, badges

For some reason, I had an edit accepted to a tag (two actually) but no badge. Is this a bug, or is there something in badge qualifications that requires more?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you **created** those two tag wikis, technically you didn't edit them.  If you actually change or tweak an **existing** tag wiki, then you will get the badge.  But creating or filling in blank tag wikis doesn't count as "editing.

Comment: Huh. Does that still count as a bug?

Comment: no, I think that is purposeful @soandos.

Comment: Then should the tag edit button be edited from "help us edit this tag" to "create a new tag" or something?

Comment: Editing from blank is the same as create a new. @soa

Comment: I'm saying to change the text on the link is all.

Comment: Looks like by-design :D